# ¿Como ajustar la hora del servidor a la hora actual de mi zona geográfica?

Tags: date

Estoy teniendo el detalle de que al presentar la hora con PHP:

```
echo "La hora actual es: ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Pues me presenta por ejemplo la hora del servidor por ejemplo el resultado podría ser:

`La hora actual es: 2020-05-08 21:05:47`

Sin embargo en mi zona geográfica que es México Central en realidad son las 4 de la tarde, lo que significa que estoy defasado como 5 horas.

¿Cómo puedo ajustar esto en el servidor o en mi código para poder manejar todo con mi hora correcta de mi lugar geográfico?

Gracias

Comment: Si necesitas que el servidor se actualice y mantenga la hora sincronizada, puedes configurar el servicio NTP. Si sólo necesitas fijar una zona geográfica para PHP, la respuesta que te dan debería bastar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que modificar tu archivo PHP.ini colocando tu zona horaria, por ejemplo, `date.timezone = America/El_Salvador`, aquí puedes ver las zonas horarias (México no tiene solo 1) [Zonas horarias PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.america.php), luego reinicia los servicios y verifica si esta correcta. Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Modifica en el archivo `php.ini` en `date.timezone=America/Mexico_City` o bien directamente en el código `date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');`