# FECHA CAMBIA DESPUES DE LAS 6:00 PM PHP

Tags: php, date

Hola mi duda es que intento insertar una fecha a una base de datos, solo que por ejemplo si es 17 de agosto antes de las 6:00 p.m. me agrega la fecha del 17, después de las 6:00 p.m. ya me la agrega como 18 de agosto, quisiera saber como corregirlo

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
$meses = [
    1 => "Enero", 
    2 => "Febrero", 
    3 => "Marzo", 
    4 => "Abril", 
    5 => "Mayo",
    6 => "Junio",
    7 => "Julio",
    8 => "Agosto",
    9 => "Septiembre",
    10 => "Octubre",
    11 => "Noviembre",
    12 => "Diciembre"
];
$fecha = "Ciudad de México a " . date("j") . " de " . $meses[intval(date("m"))]. " del " . date("Y");
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto tu pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/353801/como-ajustar-la-hora-del-servidor-a-la-hora-actual-de-mi-zona-geogr%c3%a1fica/353809#353809

Comment: Si, muchas gracias =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalmente, las fechas adquieren la zona horaria por defecto del servidor.

Eso se puede cambiar a nivel global o solamente para el contexto actual, todo depende de los usos de tu servidor.

En cualquier caso te recomiendo trabajar la fechas con objetos `DateTime` porque son mucho más versátiles y usarías un solo objeto.

Por ejemplo, para establecer la zona horaria de México en tu fecha basta con esto:

```
$mDate=new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City'));
```

Si vemos por dentro a `$mDate` mediante `var_dump($mDate);` veremos el objeto:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2020-08-17 16:10:30.220715"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(19) "America/Mexico_City"
}
```

Y tu cadena se puede construir así:

```
$fecha = "Ciudad de México a " . $mDate->format("j") . " de " . $meses[$mDate->format("n")]. " del " . $mDate->format("Y");
echo $fecha;
```

**Salida:**

```
Ciudad de México a 17 de Agosto del 2020
```

---

Si quieres cambiar la zona horaria para todo el contexto del script, puedes usar [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), por ejemplo:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
```

Si seguido de esto crear cualquier fecha, adquirirá **en ese script** la zona horaria de México.

La zona horaria se puede cambiar también a nivel global de PHP, modificando el archivo `php.ini`, mediante una entrada como esta:

```
date.timezone=America/Mexico_City
```

En ese caso **todas las fechas** en todos los contextos tendrán esa zona horaria, salvo que se especifique lo contrario de forma explícita. Ten cuidado si vas a modificar `php.ini`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo intente y me resulto perfectamente